# SBCL: running from bash and exiting back to bash

Tags: bash, shell, lisp, sbcl

I'm new to SBCL and I'm trying to run Lisp scripts stored in text files from a bash terminal.

This is what I write at the beginning of the file as referenced at 
http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Running-from-Shell

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sbcl --script
(write-line "Hello, World!")
```

This is the way how I run it from bash terminal:

```
$ ./hello.lisp
Hello, World!
```

The problem is that the script terminates back to bash after its execution. I would like the script to not to exit back to **bash**, but to keep **sbcl interpreter** running (to be able to use predefined functions for the purposes of testing). Is there a simple way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--eval` or `-e` option.

`sbcl --eval '(write-line "Hello, World!")'`, it'll eval your code and keep you inside REPL.

Comment: Thanks, but what would be the way to do it inside a text file (the actual script)? Replacing "--script" by "--eval" in "#!/usr/local/bin/sbcl --script" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to pass your text as argument to -e option, for example wrap it inside quotes or something like that. But it looks like you doing something SBCL isn't for. Why not to put all your lisp code in .lisp file and just '(load "myfile.lisp")` from SBCL? What is your full use-case?

Comment: I would like to define a new function in "myfile.lisp". Later I want to use this function in **SBCL**. If I try `(load "myfile.lisp")` it always evaluates as **T** and I am not able to use the function defined in that file. The content of **myfile.lisp** is: `(defun sumgr (x y z) (> (+ x y) z))`. The error SBCL shows is: **debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE: The variable SUMGR is unbound.**

Comment: It looks like you doing something wrong. sbcl --load myfile.lisp and then call to function also fails?

Comment: `sbcl --load myfile.lisp` works. This solved my problem. Thanks.